# A foreign key value has no matching primary key value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

why do i get

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (FAUZI.NIL_NIM_FK) violated - parent key not found
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
*Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
*Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key. ?
```

This is the structure of the database table :

[image]

```
    alter table nilai
add
( 
constraint nil_kd_makul_fk foreign key(kd_makul) references 
makul(kd_makul),
constraint nil_nim_fk foreign key(nim) references mahasiswa(nim)
on delete cascade
)
```

insert into makul

select 'A1','Jarkom',4,4 from dual

union all

select 'A2','Keamanan Data',3,5 from dual

union all

select 'A3','Jarkom 2',4,4 from dual

/

```
NAMA                           JURUSAN                        TGL_LAHIR                 JK ALAMAT                         STATUS               NIM                  
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------- -- ------------------------------ -------------------- -------------------- 
mas mas                        SI                             21-01-1994                                                                       123                  
fauzi                          TI                             14-09-1991                                                                       124                  
zainn                          EKONOMI                        03-03-2014
```

i get error, then i write syntax :

```
insert into nilai
    select 'A1','123',60,70,80 from dual
    union all
    select 'A2','124',30,100,90 from dual
    union all
    select 'A3','125',40,80,70 from dual
    /
```

an error :

```
  Error report:
    SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (FAUZI.NIL_NIM_FK) violated - parent key not found
    02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
    *Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
    *Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.
```

Comment: problem is here `constraint nil_nim_fk foreign key(nim) references mahasiswa(nim)
on delete cascade`.check your mahasiswa table and see if the data 123,124,125 exist